# how do make use pyspark groupby or join database column

Tags: python, pyspark

thisis my assessment about pyspark, given this sample database

```
CLIENTNUM,Customer_Age,Gender,Education_Level,Income_Category,Card_Category,Months_on_book,Credit_Limit,Total_Trans_Amt,Total_Trans_Ct
768805383,45,M,High School,$60K - $80K,Blue,39,12691,1144,42
818770008,49,F,Graduate,Less than $40K,Blue,44,8256,1291,33
713982108,51,M,Graduate,$80K - $120K,Blue,36,3418,1887,20
769911858,40,F,High School,Less than $40K,Blue,34,3313,1171,20
709106358,40,M,Uneducated,$60K - $80K,Blue,21,4716,816,28
713061558,44,M,Graduate,$40K - $60K,Blue,36,4010,1088,24
810347208,51,M,Unknown,$120K +,Gold,46,34516,1330,31
818906208,32,M,High School,$60K - $80K,Silver,27,29081,1538,36
710930508,37,M,Uneducated,$60K - $80K,Blue,36,22352,1350,24
719661558,48,M,Graduate,$80K - $120K,Blue,36,11656,1441,32
```

I trying to combine the Income_Category and Credit_Limit together, then group by income_category and he sum the credits of each income_category then find out the smallest amount, but I have no idea what to do

the question require me to determin Which income category has the least amount of total credit limit
and this is what I trying below

```
WHData = spark.read.option("header", True).csv("file:///home/prac/test3/input/Cre
ditCard.csv")

credits = WHData.rdd.map(lambda x: x[7])
income = WHData.rdd.map(lambda x: x[4])
 
joined_data = WHData.rdd.map(lambda x: x[7]).join(WHData.rdd.map(lambda x: x[4]))
```

all of these are not working, I have no idea what to do

Answer (score 0):

#### Code

```
# Find total credit limit per income category
sum_ = WHData.groupBy('Income_Category').agg(F.sum('Credit_Limit').alias('Credit_Limit'))

# Aggregate to find minimum total credit limit 
min_ = sum_.agg(F.min('Credit_Limit')).first()[0]

# filter the rows having where total equals to minimum
result = sum_.filter(f'Credit_Limit = {min_}')
```

#### Result

```
+---------------+------------+
|Income_Category|Credit_Limit|
+---------------+------------+
|    $40K - $60K|        4010|
+---------------+------------+
```